# Hook __dict__ on custom class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading

I want to execute a method before anything is read from my class in a transparent way (so that the caller does not have to make the call before writing to the class instance). Hooking `__getattr__` is easy, but I cannot figure out how to hook `__dict__` since `object` does not have the `__dict__` attribute.

`super().__dict__` gives `'super' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Maybe there is something else I should do to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe try hooking `__getattribute__`?

Comment: I actually had a bug there. I was mixing up `__getattr__` with `__getattribute__`.

Comment: Yes, hooking `__getattribute__` is enough.

Comment: Could you give a small example?  It's unclear to me what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the class's `__dict__` at all, in most cases (it's shared between all instances, remember), and you almost certainly never want the supertype's `__dict__`, given that (as you have just discovered) it needn't necessarily have one.

```
>>> class One:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print(super().__dict__)
...
>>> one = One()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

As you report, `object` has no `__dict__` of its own. That's because `object` instances, being built-in types, aren't allowed to acquire additional attributes so `object` is hard-coded to disallow it:

```
>>> object().someattr = "hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'someattr'
>>>
```

When you create a subclass of object in your program, however, its instances can take arbitrary attributes, which are stored in the instance `__dict__`.

```
>>> class Two:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print(self.__dict__)
...
>>> two = Two()
{}
>>> two.someattr = "hello"
>>> two.__dict__
{'someattr': 'hello'}
>>>
```

Note that the inheritance mechanism makes the `Two` class appear to have all of the attributes of `object`. The `dir()` function lets you look at an object's namespace as modified by inheritance:

```
>>> dir(Two)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
'__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
'__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

Picking a random attribute, we can verify that the methods present on `Two` are actually inherited from `object`:

```
>>> Two.__delattr__ is object.__delattr__
True
>>>
```

Comment: Good answer!  I have no idea if it answers his question, since I can't figure out what he's asking. :(